# YouTube JavaScript API: use of "unstarted" state

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

From the player documentation: "When the player first loads a video, it will broadcast an unstarted (-1) event."

What's the intended use of this event? That is, what would my host code do differently, as a consequence of seeing it, than it would if the state didn't exist? The example code I've seen does nothing but log it.

Comment: In android device it throws unstarted and stays in that state itself it will not go to other state, Could you please suggest the solution for it, I am using javascript to autoplay the video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't imagine that it's very useful. I don't think there's some deeper truth that you're missing out on. I assume it reflects a state that's mainly used internally by the player itself and it was exposed in the API for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a good way to detect if autoplay is enabled.  I.e. "unstarted" would happen on platforms that don't support autoplay but was attempted, but "playing" would be the event for other systems.

Comment: In my experience, even if autoplay isn't set, the video state changes to 'cued' once it has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I've been finding the `-1` tripping up some of my logic so decided to just ignore it and hope for the best.

I actually see a sequence of `-1, 3, -1` with less than 1ms between each event. So if your logic depends any sort of state machine transitions between states you may need to consider that.

Also watch out for this [if you explicitly use](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) `stopVideo()`

> Important: Unlike the pauseVideo function, which leaves the player in
> the paused (2) state, the stopVideo function could put the player into
> any not-playing state, including ended (0), paused (2), video cued (5)
> or unstarted (-1).

Generally you should use `pauseVideo()` which according to this won't result in -1.